# Enable Apex Classes - Sometimes Only Global, Sometimes Includes Public

Tags: managed-package, class, profile, security, permissions

I have a managed package that I distribute to clients and I'm running into a curious situation trying to help one install. I have noticed that in the Enable Apex Classes for their System Administrator profile, that it only shows a list of my classes that are declared as global. I have another client though whose System Administrator can see all of my apex classes whether they are global or just public.

Is there a setting that is allowing this difference in behavior?

Comment: I can't confirm this, but it's probably a difference of versions (e.g. Spring 16 vs Summer 16)? Allowing access on public classes doesn't make sense anyways, since you can't run them outside of the package, and automatically have all the access they need *inside* the package.